# Command executes in vim when switching nodes/windows

Tags: linux, vim

When in Vim and I switch the focussed window to the terminal running Vim, I see a command being executed. I'm unable to identify what the command/shortcut is that is being triggered or why.

**What I tried**

To move the focus from and to my terminal running Vim without anything happening.

**What I was expecting**

Nothing to happen and that I could just continue working.

**What actually resulted**

A command executes searching the word I had selected and showing the lines with the line numbers. Making me press enter before I can start using Vim again.

Couldn't identify what is being executed.

Nothing I can find and tried gives me the same output.

Which is:

```
<filename>
<index>: <line number> <line>
<index>: <line number> <line>
...
```

**Example:**

Changing a script to take screenshots `~/.config/bspwm/scripts/screenshot.sh`

My caret is on the word `option0`

Move to another node/window with the mouse or keybinds (Super + hjkl)

Move back and at the bottom of my terminal I see:

```
.config/bspwm/scripts/screenshot.sh
  1:    4 option0='area to clip'
  2:    8 options="$option0\n$option1"
  3:   15   "$option0")
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

**Environment**

```
Operating System: EndeavourOS
Window manager: bspwm
Kernel: Linux 6.3.7-arch1-1
Architecture: x86-64
```

no ~/.vimrc

`vim --version` output:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 9.0 (2022 Jun 28, compiled May 20 2023 16:56:14)
Included patches: 1-1572
Compiled by Arch Linux
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl               +file_in_path      +mouse_urxvt       -tag_any_white
+arabic            +find_in_path      +mouse_xterm       +tcl/dyn
+autocmd           +float             +multi_byte        +termguicolors
+autochdir         +folding           +multi_lang        +terminal
-autoservername    -footer            -mzscheme          +terminfo
-balloon_eval      +fork()            +netbeans_intg     +termresponse
+balloon_eval_term +gettext           +num64             +textobjects
-browse            -hangul_input      +packages          +textprop
++builtin_terms    +iconv             +path_extra        +timers
+byte_offset       +insert_expand     +perl/dyn          +title
+channel           +ipv6              +persistent_undo   -toolbar
+cindent           +job               +popupwin          +user_commands
-clientserver      +jumplist          +postscript        +vartabs
-clipboard         +keymap            +printer           +vertsplit
+cmdline_compl     +lambda            +profile           +vim9script
+cmdline_hist      +langmap           -python            +viminfo
+cmdline_info      +libcall           +python3/dyn       +virtualedit
+comments          +linebreak         +quickfix          +visual
+conceal           +lispindent        +reltime           +visualextra
+cryptv            +listcmds          +rightleft         +vreplace
+cscope            +localmap          +ruby/dyn          +wildignore
+cursorbind        +lua/dyn           +scrollbind        +wildmenu
+cursorshape       +menu              +signs             +windows
+dialog_con        +mksession         +smartindent       +writebackup
+diff              +modify_fname      -sodium            -X11
+digraphs          +mouse             -sound             -xfontset
-dnd               -mouseshape        +spell             -xim
-ebcdic            +mouse_dec         +startuptime       -xpm
+emacs_tags        +mouse_gpm         +statusline        -xsmp
+eval              -mouse_jsbterm     -sun_workshop      -xterm_clipboard
+ex_extra          +mouse_netterm     +syntax            -xterm_save
+extra_search      +mouse_sgr         +tag_binary        
-farsi             -mouse_sysmouse    -tag_old_static    
   system vimrc file: "/etc/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe -fno-plt -fexceptions -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -g -ffile-prefix-map=/build/vim/src=/usr/src/debug/vim -flto=auto -D_REENTRANT -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 
Linking: gcc -Wl,-E -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib/perl5/5.36/core_perl/CORE -Wl,-O1,--sort-common,--as-needed,-z,relro,-z,now -flto=auto -L/usr/local/lib -o vim -lm -ltinfo -lelf -lacl -lattr -lgpm -Wl,-E -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib/perl5/5.36/core_perl/CORE -Wl,-O1,--sort-common,--as-needed,-z,relro,-z,now -flto=auto -fstack-protector-strong -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib/perl5/5.36/core_perl/CORE -lperl -lpthread -ldl -lm -lcrypt -lutil -lc -L/usr/lib -ltclstub8.6 -ldl -lz -lpthread -lm
```

Comment: Does it also happen when you start `vim --clean`?

Comment: Vim doesn't know of the `Super` key so it is probably receiving (or misinterpreting what it is receiving as) one of the key sequences documented under `:help include-search` when you press `Super+<key>`. You can try to capture it in insert mode by pressing `<C-v>`, then `Super-<key>`.

Comment: @Friedrich same thing, I don't have a .vimrc file btw, just installed without configuring it.

Comment: @romainl you're onto something, if I type [I (bracket and capital i) I get the same result as refocussing a window so I'm guessing something is sending that when refocussing.
At least now I know it's include-search and I'm already a step forward to fixing this, thank you.

Comment: Apparently it's something due to my terminal, alacritty. It doesn't happen on xfce4-terminal which is default installed. So I think this has nothing to do with vim nor bspwm.

Comment: Alacritty again.

Comment: worst thing is, it's not happening anymore... And I can't find a way to reproduce.
Might have been fixed by updating Alacritty, I updated all my packages and rebooted. Could have also just been the reboot.
Maybe I should just choose a terminal with less problems if it comes back.
Tnx for the help @romainl

Comment: Just checked pacman logs, alacritty didn't update, maybe something else updating fixed it, but it was a long list... So anyone with the same problem (damn this is sad) try rebooting. *shrug*